# Angular, обновить компонент без перезагрузки

Tags: angular5, angular-routing

На одной странице присутствуют несколько `routerLink`, ведут на `notes/:id`:

```
routerLink="notes/1"
routerLink="notes/2"
routerLink="notes/3"
...
```

В том же родительском компоненте в `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` загружается компонент `NoteView`, который по `id` находит и выводит инфу.
При переходе между ссылками `id` в адресной строке меняется но компонент не перезагружается, висит с тем `id`, который был открыт первым.
Как заставить компонент обновляться каждый раз при переходе по другой ссылке? `Event` при каждом клике по ссылке и `EventListner` был бы слишком громоздким решением, таких компонентов будет несколько.

Роуты такие:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: TodoAppParentComponent,
    children: [{
      path: 'notes',
      children: [{
        path: ':id', // id в ссылке меняется но компонент остается неизменным
        component: NoteViewComponent
      }]
    }]
  }
];
```

Класс проблемного компонента

```
export class NoteViewComponent implements OnInit {

  id: string = null;
  note: object = null;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']; // не срабатывает при переходе по разным routerLink, как сделать чтоб срабатывал?
    this.note = {
      title: 'Пример заголовка, заметка',
      body: `lorem....`
    };
  }
}
```

HTML шаблон компонента

```
<p>
  id: {{id}}
</p>
<div *ngIf="note">
  <h3>{{note.title}}</h3>
  <hr>
  <div class="body" innerHTML="{{note.body}}"></div>
</div>
```

Скрин
[image: в URL id=2, но компонент остался с 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это стандартное поведение роутера при переходе между одним и тем же компонентом, это называется `reuse`. Роутер инстанциирует компонент только 1 раз и не будет вызывать `ngOnDestroy` и конструктор каждый раз при переходе с `/notes/1` на `/notes/2`. Самое быстрое решение - подписаться на изменение параметров:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators/takeUntil';

@Component({ ... })
export class NoteViewComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private destroy$ = new Subject<undefined>();

    public id: string = null;

    public note: object = null;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.route.params.pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        ).subscribe((params: Params) => {
            this.id = params.id;
            this.note = {
                title: 'blah blah',
                body: 'lorem...'
            };
        });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```